# Nothing seems to happen when I try to count vowels and consonants

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop

I need to use while loop.
error: bad operand type for binary operator ||.
first type: boolean
secod type: char

> Assume that the letters A, E, I, O and U are vowels; any thing else is
> consonant. Write a program that prompts the user to enter a string
> (that consists only of letters - no numbers), and displays the number
> of vowels and consonants in the string. Use a while loop.

Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
   System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
   String s = input.nextLine();
   s = s.toUpperCase().trim();
        
   int vowels = 0;
   int consonants = 0;  
        
   int i = 0;
    
   while (i < s.length()){
   char ch = s.charAt(i);
            
       if(ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I'|| ch = 'O' || ch == 'U')
       {
       ++vowels;
       }
       else {
       consonants++;
                }
i++;
    System.out.println("The number of vowels is " + vowels);
    System.out.println("The number of consonants is " + consonants);
            
        }
    
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Avoiding the "there's too much code and not enough text" quality checker by just copying and pasting the same text multiple times really doesn't help. It actually made it harder for me to understand what you're asking. If you'd gone into more detail about what you mean by "nothing happen" - in particular, my guess is that the code *never terminates, it keeps running* it's unlikely the quality checker would have complained.

Comment: Maybe you would like to increase `i` sometimes.

Comment: Define "nothing happens". Does it loop forever? Does it just stop? Does it hang? Is there an error message?

Comment: Hint: try stepping through the code in a debugger. That will help you to understand what's wrong, I suspect... along with Federico's hint.

Comment: Hint: forget to increment i

Comment: the loop no end never. I tried to modified the program but never work. I just need to count how many vowels and consonants de sentence welcome java has

Comment: I can run this program because I have an error: bad operand types for binary operators ||. First: Boolean . Second: char

Comment: I posted a solution for my program. BUT I would like to know How to solve my original program. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for my program. Below you can see the new program. This one is running. No problems.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
String s = input.nextLine();

int vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0; 
        
int i = 0;
    
while (i < s.length()){
    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
        if (Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) == 'A' ||
           Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) == 'E' ||
           Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) == 'I' ||
           Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) == 'O' ||
           Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) == 'U') 
           vowels++;
           }else{
           consonants++;
           }
           i++;
        }       
        System.out.println("The number of vowels is " + vowels);
        System.out.println("The number of consonants is " + consonants);
```

OUTPUT:
run:
Enter a sentence: We need to plan the next summer
The number of vowels is 9
The number of consonants is 6
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 0 seconds)

Comment: This solution will get stuck in an endless loop again if you put in a string with a non-letter character, for example: `Hello World.`